# yeoman coffeescript autocompile - not getting any errors

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, yeoman, gruntjs

I'm using yeoman and its coffeescript autocompile task, but when there's an error in *.coffee file, it doesn't get me any notification.

Everything is set to default:

```
grunt.initConfig({
yeoman: yeomanConfig,
watch: {
  coffee: {
    files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.coffee'],
    tasks: ['coffee:dist']
  }...
```

Another thing is I didn't even start grunt, so I don't know how it is possible it compiles. Where can I find or turn on any compile notifications?

Thanks

Comment: Can you gist your whole Gruntfile.js and link it from your question?

Comment: where do you put your coffee files. It should be in the root of `/scripts`, I know it's a bit awark but just check it first.